# Inner join returning more rows then regular select

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT id, run_date, feed_type_id, text 
FROM myTable
WHERE run_date >= ('20140506', 'yyyymmdd') AND run_date < ('20140506', 'yyyymmdd') + 1
```

This returns me 230k rows.

When I wrap it with a WITH CLAUSE:

```
WITH daily_run as (
  SELECT     /* MATERIALZE */
    id, run_date, feed_type_id, text 
  FROM myTable
  WHERE run_date >= ('20140506', 'yyyymmdd') AND run_date < ('20140506', 'yyyymmdd') + 1)

SELECT 
id, run_date, feed_type_id, text from daily_run run;
```

This also returns me 230k rows.

However when I do a join:

```
WITH daily_run as (
SELECT /* MATERIALZE */
id, run_date, feed_type_id, text 
FROM myTable
WHERE run_date >= ('20140506', 'yyyymmdd') AND run_date < ('20140506', 'yyyymmdd') + 1)

SELECT 
run.id, run.run_date, run.feed_type_id, run.text 
FROM daily_run run 
  INNER JOIN feed_id_types types 
  ON run.feed_type_id = types.feed_type_id
```

I get an increase of 50k rows. This increase in rows happens no matter what date I run it for (not always 50k).

The other confusing part is replacing the join with a different condition:

```
SELECT 
  run.id, run.run_date, run.feed_type_id, run.text 
FROM daily_run run 
WHERE run.feed_type_id in (SELECT types.feed_type_id FROM feed_id_types types)
```

Returns the correct 230k number.

The table feed_id_types has 19 rows, and I want to join it to determine if I need to process that particular run.

Is there something I am missing from my join condition?

Comment: What is this syntax:  `run_date < ('20140506', 'yyyymmdd')`?  I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: to_date converts a given string and format to a oracle date type, in this case it will convert the date 2014/05/06 to a oracle date format. The whole condition just checks if the the run_date column is on a specific date.

Comment: I suspect duplicate value in the 'feed_id_types' table. However, to easily spot where the extra rows are coming from return counts and group by feed_type_id in each query. It should be clear which 'feed_type_id's are causing the duplicates in the query with the extra rows.

Comment: That is correct, the feed_type_id column has duplicate values, differentiated be numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have duplicate rows in feed_id_types.  Run this to find which IDs are duplicated:

```
select
    types.feed_type_id
from feed_id_types types
group by types.feed_type_id
having count(*) > 1
```

The `IN()` clause ignores the duplicates, matching on the first one it finds.  The inner join matches each row from `daily_run` to every matching row in `feed_id_types`, creating extra results.